# What is a VBA equivalent of a formula that converts an array of strings to number & retrieves MAX?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a column of unique identifiers in my table where each is constructed using: "FY" & Last 2 digits of current year & some zeroes & the increment over the last unique ID.  Examples: FY2200001, FY2200002, ..., FY2200125, ... .

To find the 'largest' ID in the column I can write a sheet formula:

```
=MAX(VALUE(RIGHT(UniqueIDs, 5)))
```

Where UniqueIDs is a named range referencing that column.

I'm struggling with doing the same in VBA.  A solution might be to just retrieve the sheet formula's result, or similar, but is there a way to do it without that helper insert?  I tried using:

```
uniqueID = WorksheetFunction.Max(Val(Right(rngUnique, 5)))
```

Here, rngUnique is a range variable referring to thst column and uniqueID is a long variabl.  That attempt, unfortunately, returned an error as well as similar variations.

Comment: Perhaps use [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)? `uniqueID = Evaluate("=MAX(VALUE(RIGHT(UniqueIDs, 5)))")`

Comment: Sure that will work, thanks.

Comment: One issue I just noticed has to do with the context of this operation as part of a sub called by a Worksheet_Change event, since its purpose is to dynamically update new inserted rows to the incremented ID.  Apparently if a blank exists in the column the suggested method throws an error, but I was able to circumvent by temporarily putting a 0 in the relevant cell of the new row.

Comment: If your temporary solution isn't feasible then don't rely on `WorksheetFunction` - First assign a variable to `rngUnique.Value` then loop through the array and in the loop, replicate what your formula is doing but through VBA (if the last 5 characters is definitely number then you can simply assign the last 5 characters to a `Long` variable and it will convert to number directly e.g. `Dim num As Long: num = Right$(arr(i), 5)`) then use another `Long` variable to store the highest value while comparing with the current loop's value. @StarnesStudent

Comment: Could you share the two procedures you are mentioning and explain the problem in more detail? Do you really need to cram this into one line of code? I mean, you won't feel the difference between 10 or 100 microseconds which I guess this could take. You can always write the values from the range to an array and loop through the array using If statements to validate and compare the values as Raymond Wu described in more detail.

Comment: Modifying @RaymondWu's solution: `uniqueID = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("MAX(VALUE(RIGHT(""00000""&UniqueIDs, 5)))")` (substituting `ActiveSheet` for whatever sheet is appropriate)